# jquery tabs and js load content

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying use jquery ui tabs together with js and mvc3.

```
   <div class="demo">
        <div id="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab One</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab Two</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="tabs-1">
                <p>  </p>
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-2">
                <p>  </p>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
```

JsFile

```
function GetTabData(xdata) {
    $.ajax({
        url: ('/Home/GetTabData'),
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({ id: xdata }),

        success: function (result) {
            alert("OK !");
        },
        error: function () { alert("error"); }
    });
}
```

MVC3

```
public ActionResult GetTabData(string xdata)
{
    data = fetch data and return to the calling script    
    return PartialView("_TabDataPartial", data);
}
```

So the question will be pretty basic, how to bind js GetTabData() call with TabOne and TabTwo

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take advantage of HTML5 data attributes and define your links in the following way:

```
 <a href="#tabs-1" data-tabId="1" class="tabLink">Tab One</a>
```

Then in your js just bind the on click event to do the following:

```
$('.tabLink').on('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).data('tabId');
    GetTabData(id);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
 $('a').click(function(e) { 
  e.preventDefault();   
  alert($(this).attr('href'));
 //Call GEtdata here
});
```

Also you need to change this

```
 public ActionResult GetTabData(string xdata)
```

to

```
 public ActionResult GetTabData(string id)
```

coz your sending `id` in your `data` from `ajax` call